# Eclipse photon nodejs process does not end

Tags: node.js, eclipse

I am using eclipse photon to create a NodeJS project, I have installed the codemix plugin.

After creating the project from the new project menu, I started the process.
It was launched in the console.

Now I cant end the process, only option is to kill the node process from the "windows task manager"

[image]

Comment: That doesn't sound like an issue of Eclipse but a CodeMix bug: -> https://www.genuitec.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not obvious but it is hinted at in [the CodeMix Learning Center article about debugging](https://www.genuitec.com/docs/debugger/debugging-in-codemix/). Open the Debug perspective (Window->Perspective->Open Perspective->Debug) Then click on the top level node in the Debug view and then click the red terminate icon in the toolbar (or select the Terminate menu item from the context menu).